# Get exit code of a piped background process

Tags: bash, pipe, background-process, exit-code

```
someCommand 2>&1 | grep pattern &
```

How do I get the exit status of `someCommand`?

`PIPESTATUS` doesn't work because it's a background process.

I've found this [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/exit-status-of-a-piped-background-process-902557/) and it seems to work but only if I use it exactly that way. Simple `echo`ing to the screen doesn't seem to work. I was wondering if it's possible to get the exit code without creating temporary files.

Comment: Show in what way `wait` doesn't work.

Comment: @n.m. Did you try it out, yourself?  `ls -lazork | awk '{print $9}' & pid_ls=$!; wait $pid_ls; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` prints `0` to the screen.  If it worked, it would print `2` because of the failed `ls` command.

Answer (score 3):

In bash you could do :

```
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
```

Example :

```
$ ls -l | grep somefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me     32 May  4 15:47 somefile
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
0 0

$ ls -l 1>/dev/null | grep while
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
0 1
```

**For piped foreground processes**

In case of a script say testscript.sh which contains :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Some Stuff"
exit 29 # Some random exit code for testing
```

do

```
$./testscript.sh | grep somestuff
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
29 1
```

**For piped background processes**

**Method 1:** Using pipefail

For testscript.sh which contains :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail  
#set -o pipefail causes a pipeline to produce a failure return code
#If a command fails, set -e will make the whole script exit,
cat nonexistingfile # this command fails
echo "Some Stuff"
exit 29
```

Do

```
$ ./testscript.sh 2>/dev/null | grep Some &
[2] 7684
$ fg 2
bash: fg: job has terminated
[2]-  Exit 1         ./testscript.sh 2> /dev/null | grep --color=auto Some
```

You get an the exit status 1 from which you conclude that the script failed.

Had `cat nonexistingfile` been removed you would have got:

```
[2]-  Done                    ./37257668.sh 2> /dev/null | grep --color=auto Some
```

*Disdvantage* : pipefail will return a one for all exit code that is not specific to the command that failed

**Method 2 :** Source the shell script

```
$ . ./testscript.sh 2>/dev/null | grep Some & #mind the dot in the beginning
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
29 0
```

**Final Touch**

If you suspect a single command to fail in a shell script,test script, you could do below :

```
#no shebang
echo "Some Stuff"
ls non_existent 2>/dev/null || ls__return_value=50
```

Do

```
$. ./testscript | grep "Some"

$if [ $ls__return_value -eq 50 ]; then echo "Error in ls"; fi
```

Comment: Did you read my question? I'm asking about a case with a background process and I've also written that `PIPESTATUS` doesn't work in that case.

Comment: How does one retrieve exit code here? If script returns `29` it still shows `Done` instead of `Exit 29` or sth like that.

Comment: @NPS : I am afraid `set -o pipefail` will return a `one for all exit code`  that is not specific to the command that failed, ie `Done` for success and `1` for failure. If you  redirect the `stderr`  to a file, you may get some info about the command that failed.

Comment: Is it possible to use method 1 when using something other than my own script (e.g. `ls`)?

Comment: @NPS : Yes you can.. But  setting `set -eo pipefail` in the terminal before `ls non_existing | grep something` will cause the parent shell to exit thus exiting the terminal iteself.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

## With a temp file

You can put the code that saves the content of PIPESTATUS in a temp file inside `{ ... }` and run it in background.  This approach would be needed if we are interested in the exit code of more than one command in the pipeline:

```
{ 
  someCommand 2>&1 | grep -- pattern
  printf "0=%s\n1=%s\n" "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" "${PIPESTATUS[1]}" > status.out
} &
wait "$!"
# grab the exit code from status.out file
```

## Without a temp file

```
{ 
  someCommand 2>&1 | grep -- pattern
  exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
} &
wait "$!"
echo $?   # this is the exit code of someCommand
```

---

> wait: wait [n]
>
> ```
> Wait for the specified process and report its termination status.  If
> N is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for,
> and the return code is zero.  N may be a process ID or a job
> specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in the job's
> pipeline are waited for.
> ```

Comment: `This approach ... more than one command in the pipeline` - I wonder how you may accomplish this. Simply put `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` after each command? Also `wait` manpage says - `wait():  on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned`. So putting a  `echo $?` after `wait "$!"`  doesn't make much sense to me as the value returned will either be a `process id` or simply `-1`.

Comment: Check `help wait` (added it to the answer).  `wait pid` blocks until pid finishes and it gives the exit code of the pid.

Comment: My answer addresses your problem of knowing what the exit code of the first part of the pipe was.  If you want to know the exit code of each part of the pipe, you need to use a temp file as described.

Comment: Hmm. I see the point about find.. :) The man page is not very clear about its exit status..

Comment: `wait` is a shell builtin.  So, `help wait` is the way.