# Bash multiple pipes and background in last, get status code of the first one

Tags: bash

I am having following code

```
process_file $2 $3 | prefix "[JIDDD: $3]" |& logger &
```

And what I would need to have is return/exitcode of the process_file function, how can I have that?

Already tried `PIPESTATUS` and variables, but as the process moved to background we don't have access anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257668/get-exit-code-of-a-piped-background-process helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the background process write the status to a file.

```
(process_file $2 $3 | prefix "[JIDDD: $3]" |& logger; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} > /tmp/process_file.$$) &
wait
status=$(</tmp/process_file.$$)
```